# My ViewControllers overlap when i change between each one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I normally use the follow method for change to another ViewController:

If I have 3 ViewControllers: VC1, VC2 and VC3

For example, if I want to swap to VC3 from VC1,

In VC1 file:

```
VC3 *myVC3 = [[VC3 alloc]initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubView:myVC3.view];
```

When I am in VC3, if I want to go VC1, I use:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperView];
```

Then I come back to VC1.

The problem is, when I have three or more ViewControllers and I am testing the application, the ViewControllers overlaps.

For example: We are in the VC1, then i Swap to VC3 and when I want to go VC2 for example, the VC1 appears.
I think that is a implementation problem. I consider this method maybe is wrong for doing the swap for ViewControllers.

How I Can resolve this? I was thinking but didnt get any solution.

Comment: You're not really using ViewControllers.. You're using 1 ViewController and add the other ViewControllers views to the first one. You should consider implementing a UINavigationController, and push/pop ViewControllers.

Comment: Try -presentViewController:animated:completion: method.

Comment: would be better to use [self presentViewController...] instead of addSubview. Then, [self dimsissViewController...] to remove

Comment: I dont want to use NavigationController. I specially need change between ViewControllers using UIButton and methods. If you guys can writte me some example would be great.

Comment: rather then removeFromSuperView and addsubview you can do hide or show view. Add at first time then show hide view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can use following steps. It may help your

1) Back to VC1

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:vc3.view];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:vc1.view];
```

2) Back to View2 means

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:vc1.view];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:vc2.view];
```

**Note:** Before doing this, all view must be in view hierarchy that is should be added as subview of baseview.

But this is not good approach to do like this type of swapping. Instead you must be play with UINavigationController.

Comment: I will try this. The data that I stored in these Views disappear or still is available¿

Comment: @Eladar I couldn't get you. What is your question?

Comment: For example, i populated a UITableView with some data, ok? Now when i use addSubView and removeFromSuperView I still have the data in the TableView. My question is if this is possible with your method.

Comment: Hey If you want to remove all tableview data means, You can set nil to  data source array and reload tableview data.

Comment: My question is not for remove, is for keep the data. Sorry for my english

Comment: Then you can create new tableview. I think you've confused fully.

Comment: The problem is, i load a lot of data from a DataBase and it takes a few seconds so, i dont want create a new TableView, i want to view my first TableView with the data.

Comment: Did you try my method? Check this and let me know. It's normally show your first tableview with the data.

Comment: Yeah, I used it and did the same that addSubView and removeFromSuperview.

Comment: your problem is `the ViewControllers overlaps.`. Correct? Is this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

As per my suggestion, it is better to use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc];
```

and to return back , use

```
[self.navigationController popViewController];
```

Comment: What is the difference from sendSubviewToBack: and bringSubviewToFront: method?

Comment: sendSubviewToBack method used to send a view to the background in the entire view hierarchy maintained by the application , while bringSubviewToFront is used to make a view visible now (make it available to foreground) which has been added earlier in the view hierarchy

Comment: Ok i can understand but, i ask what do your code do?

Comment: if your project is having navigationController as a rootViewController at that time pushViewController will push vc to the navigationController stack and present it , while popViewController will pop the current view controller from the navigationController stack and present the previously controller which has been added to the navigationController stack at last (latest)

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad approach to application flow, but for your sake you can replace these things with addSubview: and removeFromSuperview with bringSubviewToFront: (and may be sendSubViewToBack:). But once again, it's a wrong approach.

I'd suggest using UINavigationController to sort your things out, you can just hide it's navigation bar if you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i dont really need a UINavigation because i use a lot, a lot of views and i can go from 1 to 2 and to 3 then i come back to 1... Do you understand what i say? And with UINavigation you go from A to B and then come back to A, but I need more flexibility

Comment: @Eldar: have you ever heard of UINavigationController's method popToViewController:animated: ? did bringSubviewToFront: and sendSubViewToBack: help you?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the basic articles about view controller containment, hierarchy and presentation. This is a good place to start: [View Controller Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10) and specifically [Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1) from Apple's docs.